# How to highlight in yellow a specific part of a string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to highlight in yellow only the plus sign (+) of a string using jQuery.

For example:
Text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit **+**

Comment: Just have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/), it was built for this approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace a specific part of the string and wrap it. For better handling you should use a class and css for highlighting some parts.

```js
var text = $('#myspan').text();
text = text.replace('+', '<span style="color: yellow;">+</span>');
$('#myspan').html(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="myspan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit +</span>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is evil, it will destroy DOM events and trigger regeneration of the DOM!

Comment: You have to know, what you are doing :\

Answer (score 1):

Well, This is the most simplest way to do it, I guess. Just use a `span` tag and enclose whatever it is you want to change. Give it an `id`. Finally change the `css` property using that `id`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#colouring").css("color","yellow");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <span id="colouring">+</span>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Yes, this is the better way. The problem is that the code will generate from an old CMS and I cannot add classes or ids as per your suggestion.

Comment: Then don't use jquery at all.
`<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <span style="color:yellow">+</span>
</p>`